# From Buddhas point of view, is what is common called preaching unskillful not benefical?

Tags: personal-practice, teaching

Food for thought:

It's in modern or western world common regarded and even broadly taught that such as preaching, in more dhammic words, giving [a sermon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sermon), is unskillful, not the way Dhamma is taught.

Now my person like to ask if that actually is really true?

- Is preaching to be regarded as the wrong way?
- If not generally, where would be the point that preaching, teaching, giving a sermon might turn out to be not of use (either for giver nor for receiver)?
- What might be a possible "psychological" reason, or cultural reason for aversion in regard of sermons?
- Under which circumstances a possible gift turns out to *be* a kind of red flag?

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gain by means of trade and exchange]*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Buddhist philosophy but about Western culture.

Answer (score 1):

"Preaching" in the sense of "[proselytizing](https://www.google.fr/search?q=define%3Aproselytize)" is kind of unpopular among Buddhists (see also [How are Buddhists supposed to spread Buddhism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/5881/254)).
In the suttas I think that the Buddha tended to teach people who asked him a question or people who challenged him (and didn't try to impose his views on strangers), and he often taught by asking questions.

But "preaching" in the sense of "giving dhamma talks" is normal; and (Dhamma) is I think defined as one of the proper topics of speech for a monk.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if it's the appropriate time and the appropriate place and the appropriate intention.

Red flags? Like the teacher smoking cigarettes or the teacher who drinks regularly and calls it crazy wisdom or the teacher who only knows the Dhamma through just studying books and no experience? It is possible that an unexperienced teacher could lead one to liberation while missing out on it themselves, yes?